# ¿Cómo hacer que un arreglo no se pase por referencia?

Tags: java

Estoy con una duda que me surgió al estar usando arreglos en métodos y que este mismo arreglo sea modificado por ser pasado por referencia, mi duda es una forma de evitar que sea pasado por referencia(la dirección pues ya que no es como tal por referencia) y que solo los valores del arreglo sean pasados como si fuera un dato primitivo.

```
ejemplo:

int[] arreglo = {1,2};
metodoSuma(arreglo); //Al parecer como es un arreglo pasa como un objeto y se pasa la dirección
System.out.println(arreglo[0]); //Mostrara un 3 en vez de 1

void metodoSuma(int[] numeros){
     numeros[0] = numeros[0] + numeros[1];
}
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? ¿Qué has investigado/intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes en tu intento o qué no entiendes de lo que hayas investigado? Por ejemplo, [este podría ser un buen punto de partida con respecto a tu duda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/5587982).

Comment: El asunto es que el metodoSuma tiene "sideeffects" (afecta los datos de entrada, no es mal en si, pero es una practica que oculta funcionalidad), algo mas limpio que podiras hacer es retonar la suma en lugar de asignarla dentro de la funcion, y una vez fuera del metodo, la asignas donde te plazca.

Comment: otra alternativa es usar metodoSuma(arreglo.clone()) pero en ese caso, el resultado no lo puedes obtener porque no se retorna nada.

Answer (score 2):

Use el metodo clone(); para obtener una copia del arreglo.

```
    int[] arreglo = {1, 2};
    int[] otroArreglo = arreglo.clone();
    metodoSuma(otroArreglo); 
    System.out.println(arreglo[0]); 

static void metodoSuma(int[] numeros) {
    numeros[0] = numeros[0] + numeros[1];
}
```